# Show scrollbars only when user manually scrolls

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scroll

I'm working on the following `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/tabsContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edges"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />
```

This `TextView` is used to display large amount of data that I get from a `Socket`, so the content is updated by a background `Service`. The problem is that after certain amount of text, the scrollbar is enabled and each time I append a line to the `TextView`, the scrollbar starts to show and fade out every time a new line is appended to the `TextView`, as its gravity is set to `bottom`, so it gets annoying for the user.

What I want to achieve is to enable the visibility of the scrollbar only if the user scrolls manually up or down, but haven't found anything so far to implement this. What I've tried is:

- Setting the `android:scrollbars` to `none` in the layout and implement a `onClickListener`, so it would enable the `scrolling` to `vertical` and set to `none` again on release, but as this event is triggered once the user releases the screen, it didn't work.
- Same on `onLongClickListener`, same result as when a new line is appended to the `TextView`, the layout is set to the bottom of it as the `gravity` is `bottom`, so actually this listener is barely triggered.
- Same on `onDragListener`, I couldn't even achieve this to trigger, so I guess this is not recognized as a drag action.
- This class doesn't implement the `onScrollListener`.

At this point I'm out of ideas on how to implement this, so any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the vertical scroll bar before appending new text to the `TextView`, and post an event to reenable it after the text has been drawn.

Something like this:

```
textView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
textView.append("New Text");
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Of course you should reuse a single `Runnable` object for enabling the scroll bar, instead of creating a new one on every change to the text.

Note that if you set the `TextView` gravity to bottom, then it will be constantly scrolled to the bottom whenever the text is changed, regardless of any scrolling done by the user in the interim.

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll try it tomorrow and I'll post the result. Unafortunately, the gravity set to bottom is not an option, so I'll try to handle it to not add text to the `TextView` while it's clicked.